# How can I convey the meaning of "coauthored paper"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am writing an email to five authors of a paper. In the beginning of my letter I say that "I am reading your coauthored paper ####, ###". Is it appropriate? If not how can I express this meaning?

I have searched the Internet and found no such a phrase, but I thought there should be one.

Comment: I'm reading the paper you co-authored on such-and-such.

Comment: I don't understand what '###, ###' means. Are those the authors, or the title of the paper?